# D3 sunburst circle to half-circle? (Starting at 180 degrees)

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

Based on this "sunburst example":
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

How do I make it always be a half-circle starting at 180 degrees with an end angle at 360 degrees?

Comment: You could have a dummy value that covers half the circle.

Comment: That is an interesting approach ;) I am currently doing scale(-1, 1) which also works nicely if I set the x-scale to 1*Math.PI instead of 2*Math.PI. But it would be more clean to set those startAngle / endAngle up properly I think ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138625/drawing-a-sector-of-sunburst-diagram-using-d3-js