# Drawing a sector of sunburst diagram using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I need to draw a sunburst diagram like this:

[image]

As you can see , this is actually a sector of sunburst diagram. Can I set a startAngle and endAngle for the main circle/arc?


**Edit:**
My diagram is like:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423

Comment: You should add some links to play with, a demo/JSFiddle ? Also is it a zoomable (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373) or sequence (https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426) sunburst ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

[image]

Here is the changing part :

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([Math.PI, radius * radius]) // Previoulsy : .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x - Math.PI / 2; }) // Previously : .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - Math.PI / 2; }) // Previously : .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });
```

See live demo : [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oksbd0pL/)

Comment: Ah nice! Can you put labels on it, too?

Comment: @Daniel I suggest you take a look here: http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307 to see how to integrate labels.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can set startAngle and endAngle to circle.

see code snippest from sunburst diagram.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
        .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.y ? y(d.y) : d.y); })
        .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });
```